# word wrapping block of text with variable font/formatting using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, text, mfc, word-wrap

I need to draw an arbitrary string directly on the screen (not inside a rich text control) using MFC and/or the Windows API. Characters within the string can vary in font face or color, and can be bold, italic, underlined, or any combination of the two. Additionally, users can choose to wrap the text within bounds of their choosing, with an option to force it to fit by adjusting the font size.

I'm thinking of doing something along the lines of:

1. parsing it into a vector of substrings and their formats

   using GetCharABCWidthsFloat to calculate the widths of all the substrings

   manually calculating where the line breaks need to fall

   repeating the above iteratively with smaller fonts if necessary to make the text fit

   drawing each of the substrings individually with DrawTextW, determining their locations using the widths of the preceding substrings and the line break points

Is there a better approach? If not, are there any gotchas or tricks I should be aware of when implementing this?

(I'm aware of the DT_CALCRECT | DT_WORDBREAK flags for DrawText, but I don't think that'll work for me because a) it assumes consistent font/formatting across the whole string and b) I saw some message board posts stating that it doesn't calculate the widths of italic characters correctly. True?)

Comment: In order to perform word wrapping you'd better split a text into separate words, instead of substrings. Also, it's better to use MS Word approach and apply styles independently using offsets from the beginning of the text. I don't see resons why your apprroach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

XAML is your friend. Not natively supported without `.NET`, but there are 3rd party libraries for that (e.g. Xtreme Toolkit Pro). Here's a demonstration of the XAML Markup feature:
http://www.codejock.com/download/win32/markupsample.zip

Been using it for years. Can't complain.